# Can I determine whether a pointer is of integral type via type traits?

Tags: c++, type-traits

By using type traits, I can find out whether a type is integral or a pointer (and more). Is it also possible to find out whether the pointer being passed is that of an integral data type (int, <strike>float</strike>, char) and not an object?

**EDIT:** In addition to [Armen's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311480/can-i-determine-whether-a-pointer-is-of-integral-type-via-type-traits/7311505#7311505) answer, if anybody is using the LOKI library instead of Boost, the functionality of `remove pointer` is similar to `TypeTraits::PointeeType`

Comment: `integral data type (int,float,char)`? float too is integral?

Comment: Float is not integral, and both objects of type int, float and char are, well, objects too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::is_pointer<T>::value &&
boost::is_integral<boost::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value
```

Btw `float` is not integral. You probably need `is_arithmetic`

Comment: And if you don't have access to Boost (or if the Boost implementation uses a lot of machinery that you don't want to go near), you could start at `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` and work outwards. That said, to the extent that it's ever worth avoiding some things from Boost the things used in this answer aren't really among them since they're coming soon in C++0x.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
struct IsPointerToInt {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct IsPointerToInt<int *> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// ... other specializations for the types you are interested in ...
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question was: how can one determine if T is a pointer to an *integral* type? Your traits tell if T is a pointer in general.